# git clone requires ssh:// protocol when perhaps it shouldn't?

Tags: git, ssh

A colleague of mine has a remote git repo that I wanted to clone and he provided a url of git@his.server.com:443/repo.git. ssh is listing on port 443 in this case.

I tried to clone by doing  `git clone git@his.server.com:443/repo.git` but the operation times out.  I had thought git defaults to ssh as its protocol and I'm not sure why this does not work.

If I explicitly specify ssh in the url like `git clone ssh://git@his.server.com:443/repo.git` it works just as normal.

Is that expected git behavior?  Why does the first url not work but the second one does?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah. The "default" clone syntax is scp-like. scp URLs look like "user@host:path". Note the colon; if you use `git@his.server.com:443/repo.git`, Git thinks you're trying to clone a path `443/repo.git` from `git@his.server.com`. If you need to specify a port, you have to use the ssh-style syntax (as you ended up doing).

Comment: Or use `.ssh/config` to specify port.

Comment: Do you mean each client must edit its `~/.ssh/config`? Can't we do this server-side?