# What does the : mean at the end of this git command?

Tags: git, ssh

```
git remote add joyent yourname.no.de:repo
```

I'm assuming that this means it is using the git protocol.  I however have no idea what the :repo means at the end ... because its not a port number.  Is it the username?  Is it looking for a git repo in ~/repo?

I really just want to add a port to that command and map it to something of the form:

```
git remote add joyent ssh://user@host:1234/wherevermyrepois
```

Comment: Do note ... I don't have the ability to edit my ~/.ssh/config file because I'm working with Cloud9 IDE and they don't let you set it so please don't reply with that answer.

Comment: see also: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366718/git-clone-requires-ssh-protocol-when-perhaps-it-shouldnt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument to `git remote add` tells git how to connect to the remote repository.  In this case, the argument is `yourname.no.de:repo`, which means that it's in the format *`hostname`*:*`path`*.  The `*hostname*` part is `yourname.no.de` and names the host (computer) that has the repository.  The `*path*` part is `repo` and is the filesystem path of the repository on `yourname.no.de`.

To turn it into a URL with a port number, try this:

```
git remote add joyent git://yourname.no.de:1234/repo
```

or this:

```
git remote add joyent git://yourname.no.de:1234/~username/repo
```

where `username` is your user name.

If you need to specify a different username that your local username, try this:

```
git remote add joyent git://username@yourname.no.de:1234/~username/repo
```

Comment: Note that you've also changed the protocol used from ssh to git. This might not always be appropriate.

Comment: Turns out the problem was actually not being able to set forwardagent yes on the ssh tunnel in the command line ...